# Adjust appearance of tooltip in lien chart rendered by Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to adjust the tooltips displayed in a line chart rendered using Chart.js 2.4.0?

It recently shows both x and y value and the name of the dataset. I would need only the name of the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the configuration for **tooltip** in options. In tooltip, we have callback object. In which, you set the title to a custom function that returns the title you want to give to the tooltip.
[**sample-code**]

```
var chartInstanceHoverModeNearest = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options:{
                events:["click"],
                title : {
                    display : true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        categorySpacing: 0
                    }]
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true,
                    callbacks : {
                        title : function(){
                            return "Your Custom Title";
                        },
                        label : function(){
                            return "";
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Below are the methods in callback object. If you want to extend more you can override these methods to give custom functionality

```
callbacks : {
    afterBody:(),
    afterFooter:(),
    afterLabel:(),
    afterTitle:(),
    beforeBody:(),
    beforeFooter:(),
    beforeLabel:(),
    beforeTitle:(),
    footer:(),
    label:(tooltipItem, data),
    labelColor:(tooltipItem, chartInstance),
    title:(tooltipItems, data)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works for Chart.js 2.4.0? I put a `console.log` in both the callback methods for `title` and `label` but did not get the console output. I suspect the solution above is valid for previous versions of Chart.js